# How to get a version of a wordpress.com blog post, which is suitable for printing?

Tags: wordpress.com, printing

If there is an interesting blog post, I might want to print it out to read later. However, if I just print the default view from the wordpress.com blog, then I get a lot of redundant stuff (various links, recent comments, related posts etc.).

Many sites have a version for print, but I do not see such thing on blogs published on wordpress.com. Did I simply miss it? How can I get a printable version of an article published on a wordpress.com blog?

Comment: To be honest, I did not know there is much difference between other sites using [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) technology and [WordPress.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress.com). I've edited the post accordingly on your recommendation. (I am not sure whether I should keep the ([tag:wordpress]) tag.)

Comment: You can always use a third-party service like [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) or the [Clearly](http://evernote.com/clearly/) extension from Evernote. Or (sometimes) even the built-in Reader feature from Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Not all themes include styles for print, which would generally suppress comments and other unnecessary content. You might try one of the "read later" services (such as [Pocket](http://getpocket.com), which is what I use) which do a very good job of distilling out just the content of a blog post and should print them much "cleaner".

Of course, by this time you already have the article in a repository of items you want to *read later*, so it may be unnecessary to print it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control what features blogs published by other people have.   And even if you own the blogs, the options are limited in Wordpress.com.

If what you really need to do is read the posts off-line, then try a tool like HTTRack to store a copy of just the blog post you are interested in on your PC.